# Mongoose bmx ,serial number identification

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

A while back I bought a an old Bmx bike I'm certain it's a mongoose but I'm not sure what year I plan to restore it but I'd like to know exactly what it is first. Can anyone help with serial number reading. The number is sy6h00o680 it's late 90s I believe

Comment: Identifying BMX bikes is an exercise in futility.  There are many makers, and most of them are generic asian-sourced bikes.  Also, sellers lie to make a sale. 
 If you have authentic paper documentation (sales receipt, warranty info, etc) then that helps.  There was a trend to black-out a bike by removing all decals, which makes identification harder.  And you can buy repro transfers to label any old frame as something desirable.  The Serial number is pretty useless, because there is no central registry like for a vehicle's VIN.  Try contacting Mongoose customer support with your Serial.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the mongoose website.

http://www.mongoose.com/usa/bikes/mtb

Comment: That seems to list their current range of models only, whereas OP thinks their bike dates from the 1990s.